# Style child element by id prop using styled-component

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I'm creating `AccordionSections` for every element I get from my backend this way

```
<AccordionSection
        defaultOpen={activePackage}
        headingLevel="h3"
        id={
          activePackage
            ? `active-${packageObj.type}-${key.toString()}`
            : `${packageObj.type}-${key.toString()}`
        }
        label={label}
        key={`${key.toString()}-${packageObj.type}`}
      >
```

I'm wrapping this Accordion sections in a styled `Accordion` component:

```
<Wrapper spaceStackEnd="s">{content}</Wrapper>;
```

I want to show the label with the green colour only for the `AccordionSection` that start with ***active*** in the id:

```
const Wrapper = styled(Accordion)`
    span > {
      &:first-child {
        ${(properties) =>
          properties.id?.startsWith('active') &&
          css`
            color: green;
          `};
      }
    }
  `;
```

`Span` is because the generated elements are spans. Nothing is happening. am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter active to your component. If you have children I assume that you have multiple components. So in order to render multiple components developers usually use the map() function. The second argument of the map() function is the place of the component you want to render based on the array of data you have. you can simply do this:

> <YourComponent {...yourProps} active={index === 0? "green" :
> "black(default color you set)"} />

and then pass that active prop to your `styled-components`.
if you want know more about this you can visit this [link](https://styled-components.com/#your-first-styled-component).